# How do I enable GitHub Discussions on my repository?

Tags: github

Discussions looks super cool! I've seen it enabled on many repositories across GitHub.

How do I enable it for my own repository?

Comment: I love GitHub Discussions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a toggle in the repository settings

Answer (score 1):

If you go to settings and scroll down, you’ll see a new area for Discussions that allows you to turn it on.

Comment: I love GitHub Discussions!